# Статический метод

Tags: javascript

Как  правильно записывать статический  метод в классе до функции конструктор или после нее? Али здесь нет разницы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет никакой разницы. И стандарта тоже нет.

Обычно команда договаривается как будут располагаться методы и добавляет правило в eslint.

Можно воспользоваться, например, вот таким плагином https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-sort-class-members